# Problema con un codigo que tengo en el head

Tags: html

Hola necesito un poco de ayuda con un ocdigo que al ponerlo en el head y en el body repectivamente en vez de que se visualice la web pinta un foviddent.

ESTE SERIA EL CODIGO

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-PPL4H4C');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Pegue también este código inmediatamente después de la etiqueta  de apertura:

```
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src=https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PPL4H4C
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: ¿que es un foviddent?  ¿puedes poner exactamente el error **completo** que te da para que podamos ayudarte mejor?  ¿estas poniendo ese código en una web autorizada por google para ese id GTM-PPL4H4C?  Si no es así entonces ahi tienes el problema supongo.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.